# Timeout when getting partition info for topic published by older kafka using new kafka client

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a small Java spark service which uses [kafka client 2.11: 0.10.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11/0.10.2.1).

Following is the code which works fine when I read topics published from latest Kafka version:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, producerConfig.getBrokerConnectionString());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, producerConfig.getRetry());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, producerConfig.getBatchSize());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, producerConfig.getLingerTimeInMs());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, producerConfig.getRequestTimeout());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, producerConfig.getMaxBlockMS());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, producerConfig.getMaxIdleTime());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, maxBytesInBuffer / producerConfig.getProducersCount());
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    producers = new Producer[1];
    producers[0] = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    producers[0].partitionsFor("mYTopic").size();
```

There is a existing Kafka topic, where kafka version is 0.8.2.x
. I wanted to use the same code for this as well. But this code gives timeout in last line(`partitionsFor`) with topic published by Kafka  of version 0.8.2.x. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

in short: Kafka topic(published by 0.8.2.x) not able to read by 0.10.2.1 client

Comment: The document http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade says 0.10.2 clients cannot talk to 0.8.2 brokers.

Answer (score 0):

In general brokers are backwards compatible with respect to clients but clients are not backwards compatible with respect to brokers. This has been relaxed slightly with the latest releases but still holds for brokers older than 0.10.

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade

> Starting with version 0.10.2, Java clients (producer and consumer) have acquired the ability to communicate with older brokers. Version 0.11.0 clients can talk to version 0.10.0 or newer brokers. However, if your brokers are older than 0.10.0, you must upgrade all the brokers in the Kafka cluster before upgrading your clients. Version 0.11.0 brokers support 0.8.x and newer clients.